# Set up default option handler for ruby's OptionParser

Tags: ruby, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to get simple option handling in my ruby app.  Looks like `OptionParser` does most of what I want, though I can't figure out a way to gracefully handle unexpected arguments.

If any unexpected arguments are provided I want to treat it as if the `-h` argument was passed (show usage and quit).  I'm not seeing any way to handle that though.

If `OptionParser` can't do it, is there another library I could use for easily parsing command line arguments?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's probably a slick way to do it, but I don't know it.  I've done this:

```
  opts = OptionParser.new
  ...
  opts.on_tail("-h", "--help",
               "Show this message") do
    puts opts
    exit
  end
  begin      
    opts.parse!(argv)
  rescue OptionParser::InvalidOption => e
    puts e
    puts opts
    exit(1)
  end
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.  It works for the case I'm handling, but I'd much rather be able to set a wildcard callback for any options that aren't explicitly defined.

Comment: I'm curious why this wouldn't work for any options not explicitly defined. Won't OptionParser always raise an InvalidOption error?

Comment: @liquidki - I think it _will_ work, because OptionParser raises an InvalidOption error for undefined options.

Answer (score 0):

if you save below as test.rb

```ruby
#/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'optparse'

test = nil
help = nil
ARGV.options {|opt|
  opt.on("--test=test") {|val| test=val}
  help = opt.help
  begin
    opt.parse!
  rescue OptionParser::InvalidOption => e
    puts help
  end
}
```

and execute below in the terminal,

```
$./test.rb --foo
```

you get below.

```
Usage: test [options]
    --test=test
```